# Zend Framework 2: Fatal error - using $this when not in object context

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Here's my code, in **Module.php**:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $mvcEvent)
{
    $sm = $mvcEvent->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

    $myServiceEM = $sm->get('MyModule\Service\MyService')->getEventManager();
    $myServiceEM->attach(
        'myevent.post', ['MyModule\Controller\MyController', 'myFunction']
    );
}
```

And here's `myFunction()` in **MyModule\Controller\MyController**:

```
public function myFunction(Event $e)
{
    $myTestFunc = $this->getMyTestFunc();
}
```

But when I call `getMyTestFunc()` function this error appears:

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context

Comment: Under what context would you want to use your bootstrap to direct an event to a controller?  Seems like an anti pattern to me.  I've never seen such a case, where the right answer wasn't to defer the controller action's guts to a service, and make the event tap that same service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`['MyModule\Controller\MyController', 'myFunction']` is a [callable](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) for a [static method](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php); therefore you can't use `$this` there.
Consider

```
<?php
class Foo {
    protected $prop = 'value';
    public function memberMethod() {
        return $this->prop;
    }

    public static function staticMethod() {
        return 'static';
    }
}
echo Foo::staticMethod(), "\r\n";
// Foo::memberMethod(); // results in Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

bar( 'myevent.post', array('Foo', 'staticMethod') );
// bar( 'myevent.post', array('Foo', 'memberMethod') ); // // again: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

// to call memberFunction() you need an instance to call the method on
$foo = new Foo;
echo $foo->memberMethod(), "\r\n";
bar( 'myevent.post', array($foo, 'memberMethod') );


function bar( $something, $callback ) {
    // invoking the callback immediately
    // ZendFramework will store the callback and invoke it when the specified event occurs
    echo $callback(), "\r\n";
}
```

Now replace `function bar()` by `Zend\EventManager::attach()` and `class Foo` by `MyModule\Controller\MyController` and you're "at" the problem.

Comment: Work, but now if I try `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('MyServiceExample')` in `MyModule\Controller\MyController` this error appears: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get() on null.

Comment: @RrFe this is probly because you created it using new, so dependencies did not get injected in to the controller (like the service manager) try getting the controller from the service locator instead of doing `new MyModule\Controller\MyController`

Comment: @Otto Sandström Ok, now I use service manager, but if I try to use: `$this->redirect()->toRoute('routeName')` in `MyModule\Controller\MyController`  this error appears: Url plugin requires that controller event compose a router; none found